# How do I determine the displacement between two matrices using a two-dimensional cross-correlation function (xcorr2) in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imaging, cross-correlation

Im very new to matlab and medical imaging in general. For a project I need to finish a script that uses two matrices the "kernel" and "searchArea" to determine the displacement of the interventricular septum of the heart using the blockchaining method with multiple frames of the cardiac cycle. The "kernel" is a fraction of the orginal frame image and the "searchArea" is an area thats surrounds the kernel in the next frame. I have to use cross correlation to do this and already tried the following (this process will be repeated for all the frames):

```
crossCor = xcorr2(searchArea,kernel);
[max_cc,imax] = max(abs(crossCor(:)));
[ypeak, xpeak] = ind2sub(size(crossCor),imax(1));
            
dispLat = ypeak-size(kernel,1)
dispAx = xpeak-size(kernel,2)
```

This code was writen based on the xcorr2 documentation: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html

The code does work but the results do not meet my expectations, the script that I got provided with uses the lateral displacement (x displacement) and axial displacement (y displacement) to create tracking frames:
[image: frame 1]
[image: frame 2]
[image: frame 3]

The results should show the displacement of the septum just like in frame 1, but you can see that in frame 2 and 3 the displacement is way off.

I do not know if I'm on the right track here of giving the provided script the right displacements, but any advice or nudges in the right direction are welcome!

REMARK:
I am doing this for an introductory medical imaging course, the blue colored mesh which is used to plot the movement is created using speckle tracking, however I did not get any details on how this works which is probably intended. The Matlab script relies on the right input of axial (y) and lateral (x) displacement, the results are wrong, so my written code is probably (partly) wrong. My main intension to post this on stackoverflow is to receive feedback on my written code, because I don't know what I have done wrong.

Comment: Interesting question, I am not too experienced with cross correlation, I see in the doc example above the white cross displacement example, it suggests removing the mean. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I read the documentation and removing the mean is used in the one dimensional xcorr function. I am using an image, hence why I looked at the 2 dimensional xcorr2 function example.

Comment: I think it is also hidden in the xcorr2 doc (unless I have misunderstood something) in the line 'Use xcorr2 to find where the small image fits in the larger image. Subtract the mean value so that there are roughly equal numbers of negative and positive values.' That been said I have no idea if it will help in your situation!

Comment: I guess it is worth trying, I will report back on the results once I have tried it.

Comment: I have removed the mean just like in the example, but did not get better results. Still, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What should the colored mesh in the frames represent? The "searchArea"?

Comment: The colored mesh in the frames should represent the deformation of the interventricular septum (the white part), which is only accurate in frame 1(because there is no displacement). The kernel of frame i and the searchArea of frame i+1 are put into the xcorr2 function with the goal to find the displacement in between the frames. This displacement is then viewed as the colored mesh.

Comment: It's still not exactly clear to me what it is: does it show the position of the septum in the previous frame? Or in the current frame? Or something else completely?

Comment: It shows the displacement in the current frame, the septum position changes in the oncoming frames, the mesh should therefore also change accordingly. But this last part does not happen, the mesh is way off.

Comment: Perhaps our definition of displacement is different: to me displacement is a vector, or in this case it would be a group of vectors, starting from the initial position and going towards the final position. A mesh is not a vector or a group of them, so to me that is not the "displacement". So can you clarify what are you plotting? Perhaps also adding in the question how you are plotting it.

Comment: I concur with Matteo,  it is hard to know what you’re doing or what you’re given or what those plots represent. Please read [mre], posting minimal but complete code helps in communicating. As of now, the only thing I can do is point out how (x,y) in plots and some image processing functions are different from (i,j) or (row,column) in indexing and some other image processing functions.

Comment: I placed a remark based on Matteo's comment already, I also don't know the full story unfortunately. All I know is that I have to perform cross-correlation to find the displacement of a section of the frame (kernel i ) to the next frame (kernel i+1) and so on.

Comment: Can you share with us the whole code and data?